# There is literature critiquing the "axiom of a good reason" of Ethics?

Tags: ethics, reference-request

I would like to read literature critiquing the "axiom of a good reason", specially if it starts assuming humans are emotional beings and every human action is directly or indirectly controlled by an emotion.

Comment: I did a quick Google search for "axiom of a good reason," didn't get any pertinent results (at least, not among the first-page results, #1 referred to a fictional story and a bunch of the others were about reasons for accepting/rejecting a certain mathematical axiom). Are you asking about the principle of *sufficient* reason, and how it applies (or doesn't apply) to ethical questions?

Comment: @KristianBerry I am referring to the Affirmation that a book about ethics that did I read did about the requirements to accept some moral claim is necessary a good reason, that justifies that moral claim.